# Cambio de color Admin.LTE 3.0.5

Tags: html, bootstrap, asp.net-core, adminlte, ccs

Quisiera cambiar el color de la plantilla admin.lte 3.0.5. Especificamente el menu izquierdo. Pero no se como. He estado viendo el html y haciendo puebas pero no estoy seguro de que sea aqui:

```
<aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-blue elevation-4 ">
            <!-- Brand Logo -->
            <a href="/" class="brand-link">
```

Cualquier sugerencia por favor, es bienvenida.
Fijaos en la foto.

[image: El fondo del menu izquierdo]

---

Curiosamente ese fichero del que me hablas (_all-skins.min.css) no aparece :(

[image: El archivo no aparece]

Comment: Si deseas ponerle un color a tu gusto, diferente a los skin que vienen pues podrías customizar el archivo _all-skins.min.css que es el que trae los skins y ponerle el que desees.

Comment: Disculpa, que versión de AdminLTE estas usando?, porque la versión 2.4 por la foto que veo parece que esa tienes si traía consigo ese archivo. Si es la version 3 esta dentro de /dist/css/adminlte.min.css

Comment: Hola. Gracias por responder. Pero en ese directorio, aparece un fichero llamado: "adminlte.css" Sera este del que hablamos?

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres cambiar el color te recomiendo que crees tus propias clases de estilo en un archivo aparte, ya que recuerda que estas usando los archivos minificados del css del AdminLTE y asi solo intercambias la clase sidebar-dark-blue por tu clase css.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra manera simple de hacerlo es usar la etiqueta style y sobrescribir la clase css usando !important, te quedaría algo así.

```
 <style>
      .sidebar-dark-blue{
        background: #455279 !important;
      }
 </style>
```

Comment: Lo que tomaría tiempo sería el inspeccionar los elementos para encontrar la clase adecuada a sobreescribir. +1

Comment: Puedes hacer una copia de uno de los temas que ya trae la platilla y y solo cambias los colores, es mucho mas sencillo.

Answer (score 1):

Cómo están? Creo que hay una manera que no se dijo y es la más rápida. Van al documento "adminlte.php" que se encuentra en "config", y van hasta la opción: 'classes_sidebar' => 'sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4'.
Ahí podes cambiar a "light" el dark y luego las opciones de selección cambian si modificamos "primary" por: danger, secondary, etc.
Espero les sirva

Answer (score 1):

El color del sidebar de cambia en config/adminlte.php:

```
'classes_sidebar' => 'sidebar-dark-info elevation-4'
```

Pero creo que aqui solo te deja cambiar version dark y light.

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo encuentras en la configuracion del archivo config de AdminLTE en la carpeta config

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Admin Panel Classes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you can change the look and behavior of the admin panel.
|
| For detailed instructions you can look the admin panel classes here:
| https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/wiki/Layout-and-Styling-Configuration
|
*/

'classes_body' => '',
'classes_brand' => '',
'classes_brand_text' => '',
'classes_content_wrapper' => '',
'classes_content_header' => '',
'classes_content' => '',
'classes_sidebar' => 'sidebar-dark-info elevation-4',
'classes_sidebar_nav' => '',
'classes_topnav' => 'navbar-dark navbar-light',
'classes_topnav_nav' => 'navbar-expand',
'classes_topnav_container' => 'container',
```

En 'clases_sidebar defines la alguna clase de las que ya trae AdminLTE.